# How can I convert the data types of a DataFrame to the SQL data types?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe, sqldatatypes

I'm attempting to create an empty SQL table for a CSV file. I have also converted the dataframe datatypes to SQL datatypes. However, the date datatype has been converted into a float datatype.

```py
import pandas as pd

def generate_table_creation_query(csv_file_path, table_name):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)

    sql_data_types = {
        'int64': 'INT',
        'float64': 'FLOAT',
        'object': 'NVARCHAR(MAX)',  
        'datetime64': 'DATETIME'
    }

    column_definitions = []
    for column_name, dtype in df.dtypes.items():
        column_type = sql_data_types.get(str(dtype), 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        column_definitions.append(f'{column_name} {column_type}')

    columns_str = ',\n'.join(column_definitions)

    table_creation_query = f'''
    CREATE TABLE {table_name} (
    {columns_str}
    )
    '''
    return table_creation_query

# Example usage:
csv_file_path = 'transactions.csv'  
table_name = 'transactions'
sql_query = generate_table_creation_query(csv_file_path, table_name)
print(sql_query)
```

The code returns the ENDDATE as a float data type. Here is the resulting output:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
    CUST_ID NVARCHAR(MAX),
    START_DATE NVARCHAR(MAX),
    **END_DATE FLOAT,**
    TRANS_ID NVARCHAR(MAX),
    DATE NVARCHAR(MAX),
    YEAR INT,
    MONTH INT,
    DAY INT,
    EXP_TYPE NVARCHAR(MAX),
    AMOUNT FLOAT
    )
```

so how I can correctly convert all data types?

Comment: is CUST_ID your primary key here, if yes than why is it nvarchar(max) ? Also very important, don't store dates as nvarchar, store them as datetime2

Comment: To be honest, this looks like a terrible bad table design, I would refuse such a table in my database

Comment: your code (and i use the term loosely) bases the types on the content of csv file, apparently some of those enddate either contains float or float is the default datatype. you should explicitely specify correct data types perhaps, see  dtype parameter: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html and https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-specify-data-type-in-pandas-csv-reader/#:~:text=The%20read_csv()%20function%20in,represent%20the%20observations%20or%20samples.

Answer (score 0):

when the column's type is datetime before creating the table, use to_datetime to convert datatype.

```
df['END_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['END_DATE'], format='your date format', errors='coerce')
```